# What is the answer of this calculation?

Tags: education

```
? + ? = 8
+   +
? - ? = 6
13  8
```

What is the actual answer of this question?

Answer (score 2):

```
Solve[{
  a[1, 1] + a[1, 2] == 8,
  a[2, 1] - a[2, 2] == 6,
  a[1, 1] + a[2, 1] == 13,
  a[1, 2] + a[2, 2] == 8
  },
 {a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}
 ]
```